# Splash screen que ocupa toda la pantalla

Tags: java, android

Estoy haciendo pruebas con un ejemplo de SplashScreen y no consigo que la imagen salga con el tamaño real, siempre me sale ocupando toda la pantalla,  , he probado varias cosas sin ningún resultado.

me la muestra así

ç[image]

me gustaría que se viera así

[image]

Pongo el código para ver si alguien puede indicarme como puedo solucionarlo.

splash_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/black"/>
        <item
        android:left="50dp"
        android:right="50dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
        <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/gente" />

</layer-list>
```

themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.SplashScreen" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/gente</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debido a que usas `android:gravity="center"`. los padding no se aplican. Lo que debes realizar es usar `android:gravity="clip_horizontal"` en el bitmap y aplicar margen izquierdo y derecho:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/black"/>
        <item
        android:left="50dp"
        android:right="50dp""/>
        <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/gente"
        android:gravity="clip_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Nada, no funciona, lo he probado y continua mostrándolo a pantalla completa.

Comment: La propiedad android:scaleType="center" no te es de ayuda?

Comment: No funciona tampoco.

Comment: Quería especificar que el ejemplo no lo he hecho con Kotlin, está hecho con java, puede ser que después de los últimos cambios realizados en Android Studio en lo que respecta al Splash Screen ya no funcione con Java  igual que lo hacía antes??

Por que tengo algunos programas Java que antes creando el splash me funcionaban perfecto y ahora con las pruebas nuevas la imagen de los splash me sale siempre agrandada.

Gracias.